# Python Yahoo Stock Exchange (Web Scraping)

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm having trouble with the following code, it's suppose to print the stock prices by accessing yahoo finance but I can't figure out why its returning empty strings?

```
import urllib
import re

symbolslist = ["aapl","spy", "goog","nflx"]
i = 0
while i < len(symbolslist):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+symbolslist[i]+"&q1=1"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()

    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + symbolslist[i] + '">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print price
    i+=1
```

Edit: It works fine now, it was a syntax error. Edited the code above as well.

Comment: Both Pandas and matplot have native functions to get Yahoo quotes.

Comment: Is it yahoo or google finance you're wanting to scrape? You've used a google URL and yahoo finance in the title and description.

Comment: @kisamoto yeah my mistake, I added the wrong URL because I tried google after I couldn't get yahoo to work.

Comment: If "it works fine now", just delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just a few helpful tips for python development (and scraping):

#### Python Requests library.

The [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library is excellent at simplifying the requests process.

#### No need to use a `while` loop

`for` loops are really useful in this situation.

```
symbolslist = ["aapl","spy", "goog","nflx"]
for symbol in symbolslist:
    # Do logic here...
```

#### Use xpath over regular expressions

```
import requests
import lxml

url = "http://www.google.co.uk/finance?q="+symbol+"&q1=1"
r = requests.get(url)
xpath = '//your/xpath'
root = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
```

#### No need to compile your regular expressions each time.

Compiling regex's takes time and effort. You can abstract these out of your loop.

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + symbolslist[i] + '">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

for symbol in symbolslist:
    # do logic
```

#### External Libraries

As mentioned in the comment by `drewk` both Pandas and Matplot have native functions to get Yahoo quotes or you can use the [ystockquote](https://github.com/cgoldberg/ystockquote) library to scrape from Yahoo. This is used like so:

```
#!/bin/env python
import ystockquote

symbolslist = ["aapl","spy", "goog","nflx"]
for symbol in symbolslist:
    print (ystockquote.get_price(symbol))
```